# Java program compilation failed

Tags: class, inheritance, interface, static, non-static

While studying interface I came along this weird behaviour
When I am running this

```
    int num=20;
    public void sound();
    public void eat();
}

class Dog implements Animal{
    public void sound(){
        System.out.println("Wooof!!!!!!!");
    }
    public void eat(){
        System.out.println("Food");
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Dog dog=new Dog();
        dog.sound();
        dog.eat();
        System.out.println(Dog.num);
        //System.out.println(Dog.num1);
    }
}
```

It runs fine while If I declare a no static variable with same name i.e. num as of the one in interface like this

```
interface Animal{
    int num=20;
    public void sound();
    public void eat();
}

class Dog implements Animal{
    int num=10;
    public void sound(){
        System.out.println("Wooof!!!!!!!");
    }
    public void eat(){
        System.out.println("Food");
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Dog dog=new Dog();
        dog.sound();
        dog.eat();
        System.out.println(Dog.num);
        //System.out.println(Dog.num1);
    }
}
```

It gives this error `Main.java:22: error: non-static variable num cannot be referenced from a static context`
My question was since one from interface is static and is of class level why the child class i.e. Dog compilation fails when I declare a non static instance level variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your are trying to access `Dog` class into `System.out.println()`. Not the variable `dog` where the class has been initialized.

If variable `num` is not static is impossible to read it without initialize the class, so if you want to do `Dog.num`, that variable has to be static.

If you don't add the variable into `Dog` class, the value will be declared in the interface, but if the variable exists in the class, the compiler will try read that.